# infowindow.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: f.get is not a function in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня в верхнем компоненте подняты данные c infowindow, marker, map, надо обработать клик, чтобы окошко открывалось и закрывалось, но выскакивает ошибка

```
clickInfoWindow = (event, element) => { 
    const { map } = this.state;
    let placeID = event.currentTarget.id;
    let { allMarkers, InfoWindow } = this.state;
    let infowindow = InfoWindow.find(infowindow=>infowindow.marker.id == placeID);
    let marker = infowindow.marker;
    console.log(marker, infowindow);
    infowindow.open(marker, map);
    this.closeInfowindow();
}
```

Comment: [верхний компонент](https://gist.github.com/Natanagar/9fcc89f3dac9da6efb2fb51375e0652b) _app.js_  [map.js](https://gist.github.com/Natanagar/f0f08fe300a849aefe170d837a4d9bfb)

Comment: на какой строчке ошибка?

Comment: ошибка выпадала в консоль, проблема была решена тем, что карта передается в другой компонент как pojo поэтому нативное апи не работает, все было перенесено в компонент с картой